# Evaluate the following Lebesgue interal.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

For each $x\in (0, 1]$, consider the decimal representation $x=\cdot d_1d_2\cdots d_n\cdots$.

Define $f:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=18n$ if $x$ is irrational, where $n$ is number of zeros in the decimal representation of $x$ immediately after decimal point upto first non-zero digit of $x$.

Then the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=$

My effort:

By definitions of Lebesgue integral and $f$, we  have $$\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=\int_{\mathbb{Q}\cap (0, 1]}0\, dx+\int_{IR}f\, dx=\int_{IR}f\, dx,$$
where $IR$ is the set of irrationals in $(0, 1]$.

Further, we note that if $x>0.1$ and it is irrational, then $f(x)=0$ since it does not have any immediate zeros in the decimal representation after decimal.

Therefore, we have $$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=\int_{IR\cap (0, 0.1]}f(x)\, dx=\int_{IR, 0.01}^{0.1}f(x)\, dx+\int_{IR, 0.001}^{0.01}f(x)\, dx+\cdots,$$ where $IR$ means integrals are only over irrationals.

By definition of $f$, we have $$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=18(1)\mu([0.01, 0.1])+18(2)\mu([0.001, 0.01])+\cdots,$$ where $\mu$ denotes the measure. Therefore, we have $$ \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=18(0.09)+18(2)(0.009)+\cdots=18(0.09)\big[1+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{3}{100}+\cdots\big]\approx 2.$$

But the answer given is exactly $2$. Please help to find my mistake.

Comment: Let $A(n)$ be the set of  irrational numbers that have exactly $0$ in the first  $n$ digits in their decimal expansion.
\begin{align}
A(1)&=(\tfrac{1}{100},\tfrac{1}{10})\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
A(2)&=(\frac{1}{1000},\frac{1}{100})\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
\ldots\\
A(n)&=(\tfrac{1}{10^{n+1}},\tfrac{1}{10^n})\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{align}
Then $m(A_n)=\frac{9}{10^{n+1}}$ and 
$$\int^1_0f(x)\,dx=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int_{A_n}f(x)\,dx=18\cdot 9\sum^\infty_{n=1}n\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}=\frac{18\cdot 9}{10}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n}{10^n}=\frac{18\cdot 9}{10}\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{(1-\tfrac{1}{10})^2}=2$$

Comment: Your solution is fine, except that you did not carry out the calculation $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)\frac{1}{10^n}$ to the fullest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you write "$\approx 2$"? Didn't you care about finding the exact value of the sequence?
$$
1+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{3}{100}+\cdots = \frac{100}{81}
$$

To find the exact value, first set
$$
s(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Taking the derivative gives
$$
s'(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Now setting $x=\frac{1}{10}$ we get
$$
s'(\frac{1}{10}) = 1 + \frac{2}{10} + \frac{3}{10^2} + \cdots = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{10})^2} = \frac{100}{81}.
$$